# Drag pattern in uitable matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I want to know if it is possible to drag pattern values in matlab uitable. In a spreadsheet, to enter values from 1 to 50, you need to enter 1,2,3 and select the cells and drag. Please can this be done in matlab uitable? Regards.

Comment: thewaywewalk, the answer you provided works like magic. I am not sure what you are asking me to do.

Comment: But you couldn't change it to detect multiple patterns? - I'd like to help you more, but I don't have the time, and its not trivial, I would have to do try&error a lot as well. Let me know, if you finish this task sometime, I would be interested. Good luck!

Comment: For now I could only let the first column set incrementally and let the other columns set the same value when dragged. I only changed one or two things in your useful code. I tried making it work like in a conventional spreadsheet where you select two or more cells and drag but I got stuck. Anyway I will keep trying. Thanks so much, thewaywewalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. But not as far as comfortable as with excel.

Play around a bit with the following code, you can try to improve it or change it to your needs. I think it is a good starting point for you.

```
function fancyTable 

defaultData = randi(99,25,2);

h = figure('Position',[300 100 402 455],'numbertitle','off','MenuBar','none');
uitable(h,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1],...
              'Data', defaultData,... 
              'Tag','myTable',...
              'ColumnName', [],'RowName',[],...
              'ColumnWidth', {200 200},...
              'CellSelectionCallback',@cellSelect);
end

function cellSelect(src,evt)
try
index = evt.Indices;
data = get(src,'Data');
L = size(index,1);
rows = index(:,1);
column = index(1,2);
start = data(rows(1),column);
newdata = start:(start+L-1);
data(rows,column) = newdata';
set(src,'Data',data);
end
end
```

It creates a table with two columns:

[image]

You can select data and your desired drag pattern is applied immediately according to the first value.

---

The code is just to insert an increasing series of values at the first point of selection based on the according value. **The hardest part will be to detect the pattern!** I just evaluated the first data value `start = data(rows(1),column);` you could also require a minimal selection of 3: `start = data(rows(1:3),column);`. You probably need to work with a lot of `try`/`catch` structures to skip all unexplained cases. Or you use `switch`/`case` structures from the beginning to evaluate the length of the selection and evaluate the pattern.

**All in all it is a heavy task, I'm not sure if it's worth it. But it can be done.**

Comment: Thank you for the post. It works in increasing order as you said. I will work around your code so that I can maintain the same value when dragged. But since it can be done done(even though a heavy task), I will try whether I can handle that and give you feedback. I am very grateful. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In `uitable` you insert data (usually a matrix) to be displayed in a table. So unlike Excel the `uitable` function is merely a form of displaying your data instead of a tool to manipulate it. See for more information [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html). However, if you want to set up a row for instance running from 1 until 10 you could use the following steps:

So say one would like to display a matrix of size 10x10, e.g.
`A=magic(10);`

You can now set up a table `t` to display this matrix by

`t=uitable('Data',A);`

In your case if you want a row to be, e.g., 1 till 10, just change the matrix `A` containing your data to hold this row using

`A(1,1:10)=1:10;`

And re-execute the former command to bring up your table `t`.

Comment: Thank you for the information  on uitable stated. I do appreciate your feedback. Regards.