# Getting selected cell indices from uitable

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I have a uitable with 10 columns, which I'm populating from a db.

Now I want to know when the user choose a specific row. For example if the user chooses the 3rd record, I would like to get back the value 3, so then I could access the actual information to for example open that specific record from the path.

I found online that I would need findjobj.
I also think that the method should be implemented in here:

```
function uitable_CellSelectionCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

However I found a little information about how I should proceed.

Anyone had this problem or knows how to solve it?

Comment: answering gui questions is always hard if there is no minimal example provided. Please post **executable code** we can work with. Also check out the [tag:matlab-uitable]-tag. I contains dozens of answers which contain exactly what you need. Maybe not in the same context, but there surely will be examples.

Comment: an extensive starting point your can find [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879394/drag-pattern-in-uitable-matlab/20881323#20881323).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling the `CellSelectionCallback` you can access the `Indices` property, which is a 2 x 1 array containing the row and column indices of the cell you have selected.

Therefore in your callback, use something like this:

```
 row = eventdata.Indices(1)
 col = eventdata.Indices(2)
```

and that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid callbacks, you can use `app.UITable.Selection` in the newer versions of MATLAB where `app` is your app object and `UITable` your uitable name